# How should a "project" file be written?

Tags: json, xml, database, protocol-buffers, binaryfiles

With popular software packages, like Microsoft Word or Photoshop, we often have an option to save our progress as a "project" file and later can open that file to edit our works furthermore. This file often contains all the options and the progress that the user has made (i.e the essay you typed in Word).

So my question is, if I am doing a similar application that requires creating a similar "project" file, how should I go about this? My application is a scientific application, which means it required a lot of (multi-dimension) arrays. I understand there will be a lot of options to do this, but I would like to know the de facto way.

Here are some of the options I have outline out:

1. XML: Human readable. The size is too big and it's too much work to deal with arrays.
2. JSON: More popular/modern. Good with array.
3. Protocol Buffer: It is created by Google. Probably faster.
4. Database: Probably not a good use case since "project" files are most likely "temporary". Also, working with arrays is not very straight forward.
5. Creating your own binary format: Might be the most difficult solution for an inexperienced programmer like myself.
6. ???

I would like to get some advice from you guys. Thank you :).

Comment: Word and Photoshop do not have "project" files (i.e. meta-files that describe how other files should be loaded or used). Both Word and Photoshop use a **single file** model (`.docx` and `.psd` respectively which contains the user's work in addition to document settings).

Comment: "working with arrays" is not an adequately detailed problem description. There's a huge difference between processing gigabyte-sized ephemeral texture buffers in a GP-GPU shader vs. a simple 1-line CSV vs. streaming terabyte-sized datasets from disk while keeping memory usage low. I'm voting to close this question because we need far, far, far more detail.

Comment: If you just want to save large multi-dimensional arrays of numeric scalar values to disk then you'll probably be fine if you use your platform's built-in serialization functionality (assuming you're using Python, Java or .NET etc)

Comment: Sorry @Dai, you are absolutely right about my terminology. I guess to make my problem clearer, I don't just have multi-dimension arrays, but I also have classes (which stores my arrays and other fields). I am using Python.

Comment: StackOverflow discourages questions about application design (as distinct from pure coding problems). The reason for this is that the site is oriented towards simple questions that require factual answers, rather than to wide-ranging discussion. In practice, design questions like this depend on your project requirements and constraints: speed, space, programming language, dependencies, skills. If I were advising you on this choice, I would ask you dozens of questions about these factors before attempting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Good question. :) Only some thoughts) I'd prefer text format for the main project file. You can make diffs and open and read and modify it easily. Large ascii or binary data can be stored as serialized data in external files or in a database like SQLite from where it can be easily accessed and processed through the application. The main project has links to the external data store. My advice for the main project file is a simple XML format that can easily be transformed to JSON format. A list of `key` `value` pairs (`dict`) is good for the beginning. `value` can be of basic datatype or be an `array` or `dict`. A complicated XML tree is not good. The `key` name can also help to describe and structure data. So i'd prefer `key="rect.4711.pos.x" value="500"` and not `<rect id="4711"><pos><x>500</x>...</pos>...`. Important aspect is that the project data is portable and self-contained, and the user can see the project as a single unit even if it is a directory on the file system, for this purpose supporting some kind of zipped format of project data is good.